# How do I filter a list of words (string) by if the list element contains a string at a specific index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Say I have a word list of thousands of words. But, they're all the same length. so say for example, all 5 letter words, and I want to find all the words that have 'o' as the middle letter (3rd position, 2nd in the index since it starts from 0).

How do I go about removing all the other words in the original list so we can prune it down from there?

I'll be doing this multiple times, up to 4 times in this case, since the words would all be 5 letters exactly.

So it's like original_list = ["house", "ghost", "there", "loose"] -- stuff like that. And my output should be original_list = ["ghost", "loose"]

Ideally instead of appending to a new list, I'd rather just remove items that *don't* match from the original list. That way I can keep pruning it down from there in each iteration.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem with your code do you have?

Comment: "Ideally instead of appending to a new list, I'd rather just remove items that don't match from the original list." Why would that be ideal? "That way I can keep pruning it down from there in each iteration." that will force you to use an inefficient algorithm.

Comment: There's nothing "ideal" about your proposal. Create a new list (a simple list comprehension with condition) and re-assign that to your original variable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an iterative approach?

```
from typing import List

def remove_words(words: List[str]):
    index = 0
    while index < len(words):
        if words[index][2] != 'o':
            words.pop(index)
        else:
            index += 1
    # return words -- OPTIONAL


if __name__ == "__main__":
    original_list = ["house", "ghost", "there", "loose"]
    remove_words(original_list)
    print(original_list)  # ['ghost', 'loose']
```

#### Note on Performance

While the solution above answers the OP, it is not the most performant nor is it a "pure function" since it mutates external scope state (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

```
from timeit import timeit


def remove_words():
    # defining the list here instead of global scope because this is an impure function
    words = ["house", "ghost", "there", "loose"]
    index = 0
    while index < len(words):
        if words[index][2] != 'o':
            words.pop(index)
        else:
            index += 1


def remove_words_with_list_comprehension():
    # defining the list here to ensure fairness when testing performance
    words = ["house", "ghost", "there", "loose"]
    return [word for word in words if word[2] == 'o']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = timeit(lambda : remove_words_with_list_comprehension(), number=1000000)
    t2 = timeit(lambda : remove_words(), number=1000000)

    print(f"list comprehension: {t1}") 
    print(f"while loop: {t2}")
```

```
# OUTPUT

# list comprehension: 0.40656489999673795
# while loop: 0.5882093999971403
```